# Nested If Statement to check different IP addresses in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to work which IP addresses comes from a certain company. There are 4 different groups of IP addresses with different ranges for each company.

On sheet 1, in column (A) has all of the IP addresses listed and on sheet 2 there are 4 columns with each company name and their range of IP addresses (Columns A-D).

On sheet 1, I have a column called IP Location (Column B). In this column I want it to list what the company that should be for using the list of IP addresses in column A.

Below is the formula that I'm using:

```
=IF(A2,'IP Addresses'!A:A,IF"COMPANY NAME",A2,'IP Addresses'!A:A,IF"COMPANY NAME2",A2,'IP Addresses'!B:B,IF"COMPANY NAME3",A2,'IP Addresses'!C:C,IF"COMPANY NAME4", N/A"))))
```

In this formula if the ip location isn't listed I want it to print out N/A.

On the second sheet, I have IP addresses with 4 columns, for example:

```
Company Name:         Company Name2:    Company Name3:     Company Name4:
23.3.4.0              23.0.5.0           23.6.8.0          23.4.19.9                   
23.3.4.1              23.0.5.1           23.6.8.1                
23.3.4.2
```

If it's an IP address in company Name column 1 I want it to print out that company name, if it's an ip address in Company Name2 in Column 2 I want it to print out Company Name2 etc.

If anyone could advise where I am going wrong, I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a series of MATCH statements that work progressively through the columns.

```
=if(isnumber(MATCH(A2, 'IP Addresses'!A:A, 0)), 'IP Addresses'!A$1, 
 if(isnumber(MATCH(A2, 'IP Addresses'!B:B, 0)), 'IP Addresses'!B$1, 
 if(isnumber(MATCH(A2, 'IP Addresses'!C:C, 0)), 'IP Addresses'!C$1, 
 if(isnumber(MATCH(A2, 'IP Addresses'!D:D, 0)), 'IP Addresses'!D$1, "N/A"))))
```

[image]

Comment: when I tried your formula it said I added too many arguments.

Comment: My bad. I somehow doubled up yjr commas in the match.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped but it's only printing the same company name even though it should be printing other company names too

Comment: See my added image.

Answer (score 1):

I used `Tables` with structured references, but you can replace them with absolute or named ranges. By using structured references, your data table reference will auto-expand if you add columns or rows.

It also assumes that the data table starts in column 1.  If it starts in a different column, the formula will need to be adjusted.

This formula must be entered as an array formula by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces <kbd>{...}</kbd> around the formula.

The formula returns the error `#N/A` but you can see in the error test part where to change it to the text string `N/A` if that is preferable to you.

```
B2: =IF(OR(MAX(--(A2=Table1))=0,A2=""), NA(),INDEX(Table1[#Headers],1,MAX((A2=Table1)*COLUMN(Table1))))
```

[image]

[image]